# Maven Project creation command stuck

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to create a Jave Web project with following Maven command

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mazhar.event -DartifactId=EventBook2 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false`

and the process is stuck on `Genrating project in batch mode`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
```

Here is my system details

```
mvn -vsersion
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 20:22:22+0500)
Maven home: D:\servers\apache-maven\bin\..
Java version: 1.6.0_32, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

Comment: Which Maven version are you using?

Comment: its 3.1.1, I have added the details in question as well.

Comment: Did you try without `-DinteractiveMode=false`?

Comment: I first ran without interactive it was quick, then I ran again with interactive, this time it was quick. after some time I ran with interactive its now stuck again (It eventually creates the project but take too much time). I think its some problem with internet (or resource) its trying to access.

Comment: Try adding `-X` to the command and watch the output after `Generating project in Batch mode`.

Comment: It stuck on `[DEBUG] Searching for remote catalog: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml`

Comment: You obviously have a connection problem. Try temporarily disabling your virus scanner and see if that helps.

Comment: I Think you should add all of this in an answer so that I can accept that may help others as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add `-X` to your command to enable Maven's debug logging.

If it's stuck on something like

```
[DEBUG] Searching for remote catalog: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
```

you probably have a connection problem. Since it has been working for you before, you obviously don't need to configure a proxy. Instead - since you are using Windows - my guess is, that your virus scanner/personal firewall is blocking or rather "scanning" the connection, resulting in a slow response. Try temporarily disabling your virus scanner/personal firewall and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, this helped - for me, I saw `Searching for remote catalog: ` and fixed my connection.

Answer (score 14):

You can simply use local archetype-catalog.xml file instead of the remote one.

The option `-DarchetypeCatalog=internal` can do it well.

So, you are going to generate your project instantly now:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=internal -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

Since maven is trying to lookup for archetypeArtifactId on https://artifactory.corp.chartercom.com/libs-release/archetype-catalog.xml which is having data of size more than 6.7 MB. And it stuck here at line...

`Searching for remote catalog: https://artifactory.corp.chartercom.com/libs-release/archetype-catalog.xml`

**Solution:-**

1. Download archetype-catalog.xml from https://artifactory.corp.chartercom.com/libs-release/archetype-catalog.xml
2. Keep it on `~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml`
3. Run your mvn command again with `-DarchetypeCatalog=internal` option

Answer (score 1):

If you let it stuck long enough, and you have an error like this:

```
[WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:80 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.43.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

You'll have to set the [maven proxy](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html).

I tried the same command as you, and it did generate the project (in interactive and non-interactive modes), so it must be you trying to reach the maven repo that is blocking the project generation.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
But in my case, I just want to create a java project with maven command.

Those who are facing the same issue and their only aim is to just create a project then go for the command **without -DinteractiveMode=false option**.

First I tried this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.manan.firstexample -DartifactId=firstexample -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false -X
```

at that time the command is stuck and got following error:

```
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[DEBUG] Searching for remote catalog: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
```

Then i tried command without DinteractiveMode option:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.manan.firstexample -DartifactId=firstexample -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -X
```

So, I got this error

```
Caused by java.net.ConnectionException: Connection Timed out: connect
```

But do not worry.
It has created a project. (Which solves my problem)